# How to display tab with spaces?

Tags: java, swing, tabs

I have a java program where I draw each character(in its own frame) from text file on a JPanel with grid.

[image: left- JPanel, right- text document]
Every character is in its own frame but when it comes to tabs there is a problem. I tried replacing all tabs with 8 spaces but the problem is (as seen on picture above) that it comes to inconsistency because tabs aren't always 8 chars long. **Is there a way I can figure out how many "spaces" does a tab use?** Or any other suggestions on how can I get the same layout as it is in text file?

code for drawing text:

```
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
Font font = new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 18);
g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
g2.setFont(font);
String lines[] = LabAgentComponent.PASTE.split("\\r?\\n");
for (int i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<lines[i].length(); j++) {
        g2.drawString(Character.toString(lines[i].charAt(j)), j * gridSize, (i+1) * gridSize);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the length of the string before the tab.

In `Al203` case, that would be 5. Your tab should begin at the next multiple of 8, with at least 1 space inbetween.

Here's a small class which could help you :

```
public class TabToSpaces
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(replaceTab("\tb", 8, "."));
        System.out.println(replaceTab("a\tb", 8, "."));
        System.out.println(replaceTab("abcdefg\th", 8, "."));
        System.out.println(replaceTab("abcdefgh\ti", 8, "."));
        System.out.println(replaceTab("a\tb\tc\td\te", 8, "."));
        System.out.println(replaceTab("ab\tb\tc\td\te", 8, "."));
    }

    private static String replaceTab(String string, int tabSize, String space) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\t");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int offset = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            int beforeLength = matcher.start() + offset;
            int spacesNeeded = (int) (Math.ceil((beforeLength + 1.0) / tabSize) * tabSize) - beforeLength;
            offset += spacesNeeded - 1;
            String spaces = new String(new char[spacesNeeded]).replace("\0", space);
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, spaces);
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

It outputs :

```
........b
a.......b
abcdefg.h
abcdefgh........i
a.......b.......c.......d.......e
ab......b.......c.......d.......e
```

I used dots to make it clearer where the spaces are.

Answer (score 3):

> Or any other suggestions on how can I get the same layout as it is in text file?

Just use a `JTextArea` with a `monospaced Font`. No need for custom painting.

The `JTextArea` even has a method that allows you to control the number of spaces for a given tab.

JTextArea also has a `read(...)` method to read the file directly into the text area.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out how to do what I wanted. Here is the code:

```
public void changeTabs(){
    String lines[] = PASTE.split("\\r?\\n");
    String together="";
    for (int i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<lines[i].length(); j++){
            if(Character.toString(lines[i].charAt(j)).equals("\t")){
                int spaces= Math.abs((lines[i].indexOf("\t")%8)-8);
                String tab= ("%-"+spaces+"s");
                lines[i]=lines[i].replaceFirst("\t", String.format(tab, ""));
            }
        }
    }for (int i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
        together=together.concat(lines[i]+"\n");
    }
    PASTE=together;
}
```

Comment: Yes it does. I was kinda surprised that it worked too. But it does :D